# What utilities assist in taking and annotating screen captures for local (clipboard) reuse?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, screen-capture

Is there any Mac utility that will allow me to:

1. Take a screen shot
2. Annotate it (arrows, text, etc)
3. Upload it somewhere
4. Put a link **directly** to the image on my clipboard (i.e., not to some Skitch sharing page or whatever)

Or, just as good, would be a utility that puts a screen shot in my Dropbox public folder and adds the appropriate URL to my clipboard. This is what Jing used to do, but it's being discontinued and it doesn't work very well on the retina MacBook Pro.

Comment: Unfortunately, Skitch seems to be the best option as it meets most of your conditions, but you have already rejected it.

Comment: Droplr would be another option for 3/4, but embeds the picture into a website as well

Comment: Why do you think that Jing is discontinued? I cannot find any evidence for this on the Jing homepage (http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html).

Comment: It's actually Jing pro that's going away, but I suspect Jing will die soon as well b/c they're trying to force people to use the shittier, more expensive, snagit

Answer (score 1):

[Pix.am!](http://pix.am) meets all your requirements. And since it's a lesser-known service, it has shorter URLs than services like droplr.com or Cloudapp.